# Why are there data types included in this JSON response?

Tags: json, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I'm consuming an API via `React-Native`, and data-type strings are being included in the JSON response as such:

```
{"volumeInfo": Object {
    "allowAnonLogging": false,
    "authors": Array [
      "Tim Mathers",
    ],
    "canonicalVolumeLink": "https://market.android.com/details?id=book-ZzOPDwAAQBAJ",
    "categories": Array [
      "Sports & Recreation",
    ]}
```

Notice the "Object" and "Array" type strings included in the response.

When I `curl` the same exact endpoint from my CLI, I get correctly formatted JSON as such:

```
{"volumeInfo": {
"title": "Baseball",
"subtitle": "America's Diamond Mind, 1919-1941",
"authors": [
 "Richard C. Crepeau"
],
"publisher": "U of Nebraska Press",
"publishedDate": "2000"}
```

The data from `curl` is not only coming back in the correct format, but also in a completely different order than my application. This leads me to believe that my implementation is the cause. See code below

**Action**

```
export function searchBooks(book)
{
    const url = `${BASE_URL}q=${book}&filter=free-ebooks&key=${API_KEY}`;
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(getData());
        fetch(url)
        .then(blob => blob.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            dispatch(getDataSuccess(data))
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            dispatch(getDataFailure(e.message))
        });
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    payload:[],
    fetching: false,
    error: false
}

export default function(state=initialState, action){

    switch (action.type){
        case FETCHING_DATA: return {payload:[], fetching: true, ...state}
        case FETCH_SUCCESS: return {payload:[action, ...state]}
        case ERROR: return {payload:[], error: true, ...state}       
    }
    return state;
}
```

Thank you for any clarification as to why data types are included in my JSON, and how my implementation could be the reason.

Comment: Are you failing to parse the response or seeing "Object" and "Array" in your actual rendering?  If not, I'm inclined to think this is node or your browser showing type hints as a logging feature

Comment: @Hypaethral Yes, I'm parsing the response as .json(). I'm serving the app via expo, so your inclination could be correct, but how can I know for sure?